# JavaScript locale for the more traditional Chinese numbering system?

Tags: javascript, chinese-locale

I see that there's a locale string (and what a locale string it is!) for converting a number into Chinese characters using a decimal numbering system:

```
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('zh-Hans-CN-u-nu-hanidec').format(2000));
```

> 二,〇〇〇

I'm curious if there's a way to use the more traditional numbering system, e.g.:

```
 console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('???').format(2000));
```

> 二千

I read several docs related to this topic but none of them provided a list of available number format locales.

Comment: I am going to take a wild guess that there is no way to do that. The current conversion is converting the numbers to their corresponding chinese characters. However it doesn't know how big the number is. You asking it to convert `23` to `Twenty three` but `23` with the way it works now only converts to `二三` which just reads two three

Comment: Even the 0 does not translate to the right character